# Select Style attribute using ExtJS on IE7 not working

Tags: extjs

[A very stripped down example here](http://commadot.com/jquery/experiments/extjs/).

Code:

```
function changeBackground() {
  var testDiv = Ext.get("test");
  var allStyleDivs = testDiv.select("*[style*='background-color'], *[style*='BACKGROUND-COLOR']");
  allStyleDivs.each(replaceBackground);
}

function replaceBackground(element) {
  element.setStyle('background-color','blue');
}
```

In FF, IE8, Chrome this page works fine.  IE7 says *Object doesn't support this property or method.*  **What's the dealy yo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109508-DomQuery-quot-style-quot-attribute-select-not-working-in-IE7&p=512398#post512398) on the ExtJs Forum